# Manage another AWS Accounts EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I manage AWS for my company (C1), as well as for a subsidiary (C2).  The subsidiary just has a single EC2 instance.

Is there a way (I assume via IAM) to grand the rights to C2's EC2 instance so it shows up in C1's EC2 list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Amazon calls this "Cross-Account Access". You can create an IAM policy to grant a specific IAM user access to specific services or resources. It's documented in the AWS docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/delegation-cross-acct-access.html

Do mind that you can't grant another AWS Administrator account access to your resources: C2 will have to create an IAM user.